# Jira IssueInputParameters.AddCustomFieldValue does put value to the field

Tags: java, groovy, jira

I ve installed Jira 6.4.5 and Script Runner 3.1.4. I ve create a post-function "script post-function"
I have the following script:

```
// get Application User <br>
ApplicationUser currentUser = ComponentAccessor.userUtil.getUserByName("admin") 


// get project <br>
Project project = ComponentAccessor.getProjectManager().getProjectObjByKey("TEST");

// get issuetype <br>
IssueType issueType  = ComponentAccessor.getIssueTypeSchemeManager().getIssueTypesForProject(project).find{it.name=="Task"};

// get user field <br>
CustomField csUserField = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObjectByName("userField");

//setup Input parameters <br>
IssueService issueService = ComponentAccessor.getIssueService();
IssueInputParameters issueInputParameters = new IssueInputParametersImpl();
issueInputParameters.setProjectId(project.getId()).setIssueTypeId(issueType.getId()).setSummary("summary created from script").setDescription("description created from script");
issueInputParameters.addCustomFieldValue(csUserField.getId(), "uname1");


CreateValidationResult createValidationResult = issueService.validateCreate(currentUser, issueInputParameters);

if (createValidationResult.isValid()) {
    IssueResult createResult = issueService.create( currentUser, createValidationResult);
}
```

The script is executed without errors and the issue created but the custom field "userField" does not have the value, which I am trying to pass.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use this https://answers.atlassian.com/

Answer (score 2):

I found out what is the problem. I have to put the following line before calling issueService.validateCreate():

issueInputParameters.setSkipScreenCheck(true);